# (Criticize the proof): Closed subset of metric space is complete.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a closed subset, then if $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$ which converges to $x \in Y$ in some bigger space $Y$, then I show that $x$ is a limit point of $X$ by the following argument, every ball around $x$ will contain some $x_n$ and hence every ball intersects $X$. Hence $x \in X$. Therefore every Cauchy sequence is convergent. This proves that every closed set is complete, which we know is wrong. So where did I made a mistake?

Comment: A *closed* subset of a complete metric space is complete with the restricted metric. You are are looking at subset of a complete metric space (which need not be closed) and are working with the definition of closed set in the subspace topology. The conclusion 'Hence $x\in X$' is, for $x\in Y$, however only true if $X$ is closed in $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have proven that every closed subset $X$ of a complete metric space $Y$ is itself complete.

If $Y$ is not complete, even if $X$ is closed in it, you cannot invoke some bigger complete space $Y'$, because then it's not guaranteed anymore that $X$ is closed in $Y'$.

Try with concrete examples: take $X=[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$. $X$ is closed in $\mathbb Q$, but $\mathbb Q$ itself is not complete. On the other hand, you can embed $\mathbb Q\subset\mathbb R$, but then $X$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$ anymore.

Comment: Kind of. He has shown that $ x$ is in the closure of $X$, which implies $x\in X$ (only) if $X$  is closed.

Comment: @Thomas I believe the OP probably knows the theorem that every metric space has its completion, so any Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ does converge in that completion, to some $x$. Now, $X$ is closed, so $x\in X$. Where is the mistake? I believe it is in this statement "$X$ is closed". Closed in what? In the original metric space or in some bigger completion?

Comment: Yes, you noticed the relevant point. $X$ is (always) closed in $X$, but not necessarily in $Y$. $x$ is only in the closure of $X$ wrt $X$, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument fails for $X\subset Y$ dense. If we take $(x_n)_n$ the sequence of decimal approximations (by defect) of $\sqrt 2$, then $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb Q$ but does not converge in $\mathbb Q$. However, for any $\epsilon>0$ we have $(-\epsilon+\sqrt 2,\epsilon+\sqrt 2)\cap \mathbb Q \neq \emptyset$, since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

If $(Y,d)$ is a complete metric space then for $X \subseteq Y$, the space $(X,d)$ (same metric, restricted to $X$) is complete iff $X$ is closed in $Y$.

If $X$ is closed: take a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $(X,d)$. This is also
a Cauchy sequence in $(Y,d)$ (this only depends on the mutual distances of points of the form $x_n$, and these are measured with $d$ in both cases). As $Y$ is complete under $d$, there is some $y \in Y$ such that $x_n \to y$. As all $x_n$ are in $X$, $y$ is in the closure of $X$, hence $y \in X$ (as $X$ is closed). So $y$ is also the limit of $(x_n)_n$ in $(X,d)$.

If $(X,d)$ is complete: suppose $y$ is in the closure of $X$. Then there is a sequence $(x_n)_n$ from $X$ that converges (in $(Y,d)$) to $y$. As a convergent sequence is Cauchy (this holds in all metric spaces) $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$ as well. As $(X,d)$ is by assumption complete, there is some $x \in Y$ such that $x_n \to x$ under $d$. As limits of sequences are unique, $y = x \in X$ and so $y \in X$, and $X$ is indeed closed, as it contains all points of its closure.